# Could using yield as a contextual keyword ever cause an issue

Tags: c#, language-design, backwards-compatibility, yield-return

In [Essential C#](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Essential-7-0-Addison-Wesley-Microsoft-Technology/dp/1509303588) it states:

> After C# 1.0, no new reserved keywords were introduced to C#. However,
>   some constructs in later versions use contextual keywords, which are
>   significant only in specific locations. Outside these designated
>   locations, contextual keywords have no special significance.*  By this
>   method, most C# 1.0 code is compatible with the later standards.
>
> *For example, early in the design of C# 2.0, the language designers
>   designated yield as a keyword, and Microsoft released alpha versions
>   of the C# 2.0 compiler, with yield as a designated keyword, to
>   thousands of developers. However, the language designers eventually
>   determined that by using yield return rather than yield, they could
>   ultimately avoid adding yield as a keyword because it would have no
>   special significance outside its proximity to return.

Now I don't understand this, as before c# 2.0, every method returning an IEnumerable would have had to have a return statement in it, whereas yield could be used as a contextual keyword only inside a method that returned an IEnumerable but had no return statement. eg

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetInts()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        yield i;
}
```

Since this method would not have compiled pre-C# 2.0, I don't see how this could break backwards compatability.

So my question is:

Are there any situations where using `yield` instead of `yield return` in C# would have broken backwards compatibility, or otherwise caused issues?

Comment: I'm saying that yield could be used as a contextual keyword

Comment: There are *two* statements that use the yield keyword, yield return and yield break.   Symmetry is in general a good idea, the C# designers also always considered how their choices could affect syntax highlighting and auto-completion.  Hopefully some day their meeting notes will be published so questions like this don't have to be subjective anymore.

Comment: That's fair enough. I'm just intrigued by the author of the books claim, and wondering if it's a valid one.

Comment: I'm not asking why they did it. I'm just trying to see if it's true that making yield a contextual keyword could break backwards compatibility as claimed. Hence I do not believe this question to be opinion based at all - it has exactly one correct answer, either yes, or no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    yield i;
```

This is indeed not valid without a yield keyword, but what if we add parentheses around the `i`?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    yield (i);
```

Now this a perfectly valid call of a method named `yield`. So if we interpreted `yield (i);` as a use of the contextual keyword `yield`, the meaning of this valid code would change, breaking backwards compatibility.

A more formal way to look at this would be like this: If we change the grammar of C# 2 to replace `statement: 'yield' 'return' expression ';'` with `statement: 'yield' expression ';'`, then there'll be an ambiguity between that rule and the rule for function calls because `expression` can be derived to `'(' expression ')'` and `'yield' '(' expression ')' ';'` could also be a function call in an expression statement.

#### Possible Solution 1

You could of course say that only `yield i;` (or any other expression that does not start with an opening parenthesis) should be interpreted as a use of the contextual keyword while `yield (i);` would still be seen as a method call. However that'd be quite inconsistent and surprising behavior - adding parentheses around an expression shouldn't change the semantics like that.

Also this would mean changing the above grammar rule to something like `statement: 'yield' expressionNoStartingParen ';'` and then defining `expressionNoStartingParen`, which would duplicate most of the actual definition of `expression`. That'd make the grammar pretty complicated (though you could work around that by just describing the no-starting-parenthesis requirement in words instead of in the grammar and then use a flag to track this in actual implementations (though that would probably not be an option using most parser generators)).

#### Possible Solution 2

Another way to resolve this ambiguity, which you've mentioned in comments, would be to only interpret `yield expression;` as a yield statement when inside non-void methods that do not have a return statement. This would maintain backwards-compatibility because such methods would be invalid in C# 1 anyway. However this would be somewhat inconsistent because now you could define a method named yield and call it in methods that don't use yield-statements, but not methods that do.

More importantly this isn't what contextual keyword are usually like. Normally a contextual keyword acts as an identifier whenever it's used in any place where identifiers are valid and can only be used as a keyword in places where identifiers could not occur. This would not be the case here. That's not only inconsistent with how contextual keywords usually work and would make it more difficult for readers to distinguish yield-as-a-keyword from yield-as-an-identifier, it would also make it much more difficult to implement:

Not only wouldn't you be able to tell whether `yield(x);` is a yield statement just by looking at that line (you'd need to look at the whole method); the parser wouldn't either - it would have to know whether the method contains a `return` statement. This would require two distinct definitions for bodies with and without return in the grammar - and a separate definition of what's allowed as an identifier in each one. That would be a horrible grammar to look at and also to implement.

In practice one would most likely create an ambiguous grammar and then parse `yield (x);` into a placeholder AST that contains both the possibility that it's a yield statement or a function call. Then you'd try to typecheck both and throw away the one that doesn't typecheck. This would work, but it's pretty uncommon to do and would have required extensive changes to how parsing works in the compiler and how it then works with the AST. Any other implementations of the language (Mono, Roslyn) would then also have had to deal with this complexity, making it more difficult to create new implementations.

#### Conclusion

So in conclusion, both ways to work around this issue lead to some inconsistencies and the latter is also significantly difficult to implement. Only treating `yield` as special when used together with `return` avoids the ambiguity without creating any inconsistencies and is easy to implement.

Comment: Can you show a method containing that code which would be valid in C# 1.0, and yet now has the alternative meaning in C# 2.0 please? I don't think that's possible, as any valid method in C# 1.0 would have had to have a return statement, which would indicate yield is a method, not a contextual keyword.

Comment: @YairHalberstadt I thought the question was if allowing `yield` without `return` would have broken backwards-compatibility - not whether C# 2 actually did break backwards compatibility (it didn't).

Comment: I am indeed asking that. However I'm claiming that your case wouldn't break backwards compatibility, as there exists no valid C# 1 method where the yield could be interpreted as a contextual keyword, even if not followed by return. Sorry if I didn't make myself clear.

Comment: @YairHalberstadt Okay, the "now has the alternative meaning in C# 2.0" part confused me. The code I've shown is valid in C# 1 and it does not have an alternative meaning in C# 2. But if C# 2 had implemented yield-statements `yield expression;` instead of `yield return expression;`, then it *would* have an alternative meaning. So that answers your question, right?

Comment: but that code would have had to appear inside a function. But yield would never have been interpreted as a contextual keyword in a function with a return statement, or with a void return type, so I don't think you could find a full method that was valid pre C# 2.0 but in C# 2.0 changed its meaning.

Comment: @YairHalberstadt Oh, now I see your point. You want it to be contextual not only syntactically, but semantically. That is you want to interpret `yield` differently depending on the type of the method it's in (and whether the method contains a `return` statement). That would indeed avoid the issue, but it's not how contextual keywords usually work and would be a complete and utter pain to implement (it'd make yield-statement impossible to detect at parse-time, so you'd need some kind of placeholder in the AST that's replaced during semantic analysis - that's highly unusual and complicated).

Comment: Thanks for that comment @sepp2k. I'm accepting your answer for the comment so it would be great if you put it in your answer!

Comment: @YairHalberstadt I've expanded my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about it more, I don't believe making yield a contextual keyword, even when not followed by return, could have broken backwards compatibility. However it would have led to some oddities.

eg.

```
public class yield
{

}
...
public IEnumerable<yield> GetInts()
{
    yield item;
    item = new yield(); //compiler complains - item not declared.

    yield item2 = new yield(); //compiler complains-item2 not declared.
}
```

or

```
public int yield(int x) => 5;
public IEnumerable<int> GetInts()
{
    yield (5); //does not call the yield method as expected, but yields 5 instead
}
```

So whilst none of these methods would have compiled pre C# 2.0 anyway, using yield return ducked all these issues.

Comment: Your second example gets even more complicated if you consider that the yield method might be in a base class. Base classes can change without the derived classes knowledge which is a source of many issues (aka the brittle base class problem). If yield is merely contextual you have to decide what to do in these cases: create special rules for iterator methods, issue error or warnings, or do something else. I think the compiler authors decided it was cheaper and easier to do something else, change the syntax to yield return.